Can I run sprinkler wire under the house and not bury it?
I have direct burial sprinkler wire. It's running from the controller to the solenoids under the house. Since there's no shovel risk there, is it fine to not bury it and just leave it on the ground?

That takes care of shovel risk. But not rodent risk.

Are you laying it on the ground and building the house on top of it?

@RMDman taking it through the crawl space under the house.

@matt, then staple it to the floor joists.
